# Forge Viewer error CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm working on a project using BIM360 and Forge and when I click a Revit file, the application gives me an error of:
'CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something is wrong with your setup.

Can you follow this link and click on #5.
https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/idea/viewer-app

1. Copy and paste the URN and a fresh "AccessToken", into the viewer code.  2. Save the source code as a HTML file.
2. Open the HTML in browser (running from file or from localhost, both will work).

Does that load the Revit file ?  Do you still see the CORS error ?

Comment: Hello,
I'm following the tutorial on this link (https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/3legged/ui), I managed to get the URN by accessing the ForgeViewer.js file and using the console.log in the URN variable, in the same file I used console.log in the data.acess_token variable, but it still has the same problem. This error message "onDocumentLoadFailure () - errorCode: 7" is also appearing.

Comment: can you host a small local server...  like this...  python -m SimpleHTTPServer ... and then point your browser to   http://localhost:8000/index.html   ... where you have saved your html file as index.html ?  The CORS error can sometimes appear when the browser points to file://mylocalharddrive/c/somefolder/index.html

Comment: I'm using the npm start command to upload the HTTP server, which returns this URL http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

Could you go to this RAW gist link: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wallabyway/bee2541c9f7eedac1288747f4a6aaa14/raw/c2c1f6beea41610f616ffae2f16bf32c6eaac8d8/forge-skeleton-css

now, copy-and-paste this into a text editor, and save it as 'test.html'...

then open it directly in a browser, with "file:///"
[image]ie. file:///Myfolder/test.html

You should load and view the following (screenshot)...

Does that work ?